# Is this a real "double microscope" with two stages and two sets of objectives? Is it used in biology?

Tags: microscopy

In [this US late night TV broadcast](https://youtu.be/ek4kvnBf20A?t=388)<sup>1</sup> a set has been created with some "science objects" for visual impact, and right in the center is an unusual looking optical microscope.

The bottom looks like two separate microscope bodies, each with its own stage and objective turret, but on top there is a long optical block which presumably contains several mirrors or prisms and the illumination system, topped with a binocular eyepiece.

**Question** Is this a real "double microscope" with two stages and two sets of objectives, as opposed to something that has been created for TV visual impact alone, and is this or something similar ever used in biology?

[image: Is this a real "double microscope" with two stages and two sets of objectives?] (cropped, zoomed and sharpened)

---

<sup>1</sup>Jimmy Kimmel Live, June 2, 2021

Comment: For me this doesn't make sense. Two sets of oculars is not uncommon in a teaching environment but the other way round?'

Comment: @Chris a "[comparative biology](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Heads_of_Scelidopetalon_biwenxuani_and_Amblyopus_vittatus_-_ZooKeys-317-081-g001.jpeg) microscope" perhaps?

Comment: That could work. Use two samples and then overlay images.

Comment: @Chris: But far easier to do it with two scopes with digital cameras, feeding the images into a computer.

Comment: @jamesqf four pieces of equipment (microscope, camera, computer, monitor) is not always abetter solution than one; some folks really prefer looking through a microscope *directly* than watching it on TV in a brightly lit room. The eyepieces may offer a 50° apparent FOV with black everywhere else, whereas staring at a monitor might offer half of that or less plus a room full of distractions. Imagine buying a nice pair of binoculars then putting a camera on them and viewing through your laptop, nobody does this because it's absolutely worse than simply looking through the binoculars.

Comment: @uhoh: I suspect the reason people don't put digital cameras on binoculars is that they don't want to carry the laptop around in the field.  As for the folks who prefer looking directly through the microscope, I would guess they don't wear contacts and/or suffer from eye floaters.  And then there's the issue of cost: unless someone else is paying for your equipment, an off-the-shelf microscope & digital camera are likely to cost a lot less than a special-purpose dual microscope - plus you can use them for other things.